# Firebase add inside for-loop

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm running a firebase `add` inside a map. The problem is I need to return the reference of the newly added document, but it looks like it goes to the next iteration before the `.then` of the current iteration is ran. I tried with `await` but I can't get it to work properly.

```
  taskContexts = taskContexts.map(taskContext => {
    const found = contexts.find(el => el.name === taskContext);
    // If context exists, return reference
    if (found) {
      return this.props.firebase.db.doc("/contexts/" + found.uid);
    } else {
      // If it doesn't, create new context
      // The add works, but it looks like the .then is only ran after the iteration has finished
      this.props.firebase.contexts().add({
        created: this.props.firebase.fieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        name: taskContext,
      })
      // Then return reference
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("New context added with id:");
        console.log(response.id);
        return this.props.firebase.db.doc("/contexts/" + response.id);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error adding new context: ", error);
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: Return the promise created by `add()` then use `Promise.all(taskContexts)` to wait for them all to resolve

Comment: @Phil The duplicate link didn't really help, but your comment, alongside this link from the firebase docs did: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions Not sure if you still want to close the question.

Comment: Point #4 of the accepted answer mirrors my comment so I'm not sure what is lacking

Comment: It just wasn't clear to me from that answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `Promise.all()`, it will give an array of all responses and from there, your problem would be fixed easily.

For more [Take a look](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) 
, your comment's are welcome.

*I don't have enough reputation to comment*